# TypeError: this.pingIntervalTimer.refresh is not a function

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, gulp-watch

I use the gulp for my project. When I run the task 'gulp watch', the server launches as it should, but after 500-600ms I get an error in the console "TypeError: this.pingIntervalTimer.refresh is not a function".
Gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
watch = require('gulp-watch'),
browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
gulp.task('serve', function() {
    browserSync.init({ 
        server: { 
            baseDir: "src" 
        }, 
        notify: false 
    }); 
    
});

gulp.task('watch', ['serve'], function() {
    gulp.watch('./src/*.html', browserSync.reload);
});
```

Console screenshot: [console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhrZw.jpg)

This error occurred after I updated the modules with the npm update --save command in my project folder.

Can you help me with my problem?

Comment: Take a look at this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/4390).